# This url has been identified as malicious and/or abusive

Tags: facebook

https://alsalamanty.com/

http://alsalamanty.com/

I`m a developer of Facebook login app for website. When I'm trying to save changes in my Facebook web-application settings, getting this error "Site URL has been been identified as malicious and/or abusive." I can't save anything while field "Site URL" contains my domain name. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 4):

Go to facebook.com . Try to share the url. You will get a dialog saying the url is bad and in the button there will be a link if you don't agree and you want to report it.

Comment: My URL shows no errors sharing it, but when i try adding it to the web-application settings , I get the same error @AlNahari is getting.  Any tips?

Comment: @AlNahari So my problem was a URL was good when i added it.  Let it sit there and the domain expired, when i tried adding a new one it gave me the error.  I assumed it was for the new URL i was trying to add but i was wrong.  It re-scans all of your URLs.  It was failing due to an old URL no longer being acceptable.  Removed it and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

simple solution is to disable facebook button, so that facebvook change their aggressive globalism political tactic of  changing their ways for developers constantly forcing to change their code, like google does with google login.

Other solution is to, according to:
https://www.forbes.com/sites/caroltice/2013/03/15/when-facebook-calls-you-abusive-reclaim-your-reputation/

First go to:
https://global.sitesafety.trendmicro.com/

and check if your URL appears as non safe or as Untested

Click on reclassify --> url reclassification request

Then select the option SAFE

Suggest a category

Add your email

click the button to proceed, then go to yuour email and click the link that trendmicro sent to you, then wait

other links:
https://global.sitesafety.trendmicro.com/index.php

https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/about/legal/detection-reevaluation.html